# Remove unwanted tick marks in image processing using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract the text from the below image by using Tesseract:

[image]

Tesseract gives output as: etiocsat"
If i remove the tick mark (highlighted in yellow) manually by editing the image, Tesseract gives correct text.
How can I remove the highlighted part using opencv in python?

Comment: Note: I highlighted the tick mark for explaining the problem here, but in actual image it's not marked in yellow.

Comment: Instead of removing that tick mark in the image, may be you can remove that tick mark based recognized character in the final ocr output. Eg. i got "CTLDCBGT/" as the output so it can filtered to "CTLDCBGT" by stripping the last character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter symbols directly in Tesseract:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image.png'), lang='eng', config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

Output:

```
CTLDCBGT
```

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer, but I am still getting wrong text. Maybe there is something wrong with Tesseract installation in my pc. I was able to built it from source by using link https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#windows. My aim is to deploy this application in any system. How can I do it? Should I install it directly by using the executable provided in link https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **findContours()** **OpenCV** function and remove the tick based on the area.

You have to firstly convert the image into binary and then invert the image and then remove smaller contours based on the area. Following is the code snippet to achieve this task:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

im = cv2.imread("4SPb7.png")
# RGB to grayscale conversion
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# grayscale to binary
_, im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# invert image
im_bw = 255-im_bw

# find contours
_, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# remove small components based on area
if cnts is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(cnts)):
        a = cv2.contourArea(cnts[i])
        if a < 30:
            cv2.drawContours(im_bw, cnts, i, 0, cv2.FILLED)

im_bw = 255-im_bw
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im_bw))
```

**Output:**

```
CTLDC8GT
```

**Output image:**

[image: output]

Comment: Do you always have to convert the image to greyscale? Can you remove a mark in a color photo?  I'm trying to do this on old family slides that have been digitized and I would like to keep them in color if I can.